# PyQt5 custom button with a label next to it

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I want to define a custom button with label next to it, these two should be combined as a control and there should always be no space between and won't be affected by the layout or other widgets.

```py
class ButtonCtrl(QWidget):
    """ Implemented button control with label and checkable property """
    toggled = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self,  label='', func=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        col = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.text = ['ON', 'OFF']
        self.label = QLabel(label, self)
        self.button = QPushButton('ON', self)
        col.addWidget(self.label)
        col.addWidget(self.button)
        # self.setLayout(col)
        col.setSpacing(0)
        self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.adjustSize()
        # Defaultly False
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.setChecked(False)
        self.button.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton[text='OFF']{ background-color:red; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Microsoft YaHei} QPushButton[text='ON']:checked{background-color: green; font-weight:normal}''')

        self.updateStatus(False)
        self.label.setStyleSheet('QLabel {font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Microsoft YaHei}')
        # self.label.setFont(QFont('Microsoft YaHei', 14,99))
        # self.button.setFont(QFont('Microsoft YaHei', 12, 50))
        self.button.toggled.connect(self.toggled.emit)
        self.toggled.connect(self.updateStatus)
        if func:
            self.toggled.connect(func)

    def setLabel(self, label=''):
        self.label.setText(label)

    def setChecked(self, state):
        self.button.setChecked(state)

    def setStatusText(self, on='ON', off='OFF'):
        self.text = [on, off]
        self.updateStatus(self.button.isChecked())

    def status(self):
        return self.button.isChecked()

    def updateStatus(self, state):
        if state:
            self.button.setText(self.text[0])
        else:
            self.button.setText(self.text[-1])
```

However, the label is quite far away from the button control if it is added to the main window within a QHBoxLayout and there is too much space for this custom button. In addition, if I set the alignment of the custom button as center, all of them will be aligned to center, and other alignments work as well. However, this is not exactly what I want, I hope the button and label will always be closely next to each other. Any elegant solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a stretch before the first widget *and* after the last:

```
class ButtonCtrl(QWidget):
    """ Implemented button control with label and checkable property """
    toggled = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self,  label='', func=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        col = QVBoxLayout(self)
        col.addStretch()
        self.text = ['ON', 'OFF']
        self.label = QLabel(label, self)
        self.button = QPushButton('ON', self)
        col.addWidget(self.label)
        col.addWidget(self.button)
        col.setSpacing(0)
        col.addStretch()
        # ...
```